# Wordpress stripping out custom field tags

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am using wordpress get post meta to store the value of a custom field into a variable. In this particular instance, It is actually grabbing the post's parent's custom field due to the `$post->post_parent` Here is the code:

```
<?php $cast_members = get_post_meta($post->post_parent, 'cast_members', true); ?>
    <p><?php echo $cast_members; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The custom field cast_members is a series of cast members, each in its own paragraph. For some reason wordpress is stripping out the paragraph tags and displaying all of the cast members in a continuous string. I need to retain those paragraph tags so each cast member is on its own line. Any idea why `get_post_meta` strips out tags and how to fix it?

Comment: if it helps, I am using advanced custom fields to create the custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this,

```
<?php

  $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('cast_members',$post->post_parent);
  foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
    echo "</p>". $value ."</p>";  
  }

?>
```

Or you ca use your original query but just add a `foreach` to echo out the value wrapped in `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Vinod Dalvi the answer involves using wpautop like so:

```
<p><?php echo wpautop($cast_members); ?></p>
```